# potential downside of setting UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext=true?

Tags: asp.net

ASP.Net applications originally created under .NET 4.0 and later ported to .NET 4.5 in Visual Studio will still run using the legacy ASP pipeline unless you remember to add one of these to your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

or:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
</system.web>
```

I have a couple of question here:

- if neither of these settings are present, but if I have recompiled my
  application as a .NET 4.5 (say) project and used new classes like
  System.Web.HttpClient, is my application running under .NET 4.0, .NET
  4.5, or some hybrid environment?
- I know there are some nasty deadlocks that can happen if I use the
  legacy ASP pipeline, call an async method like
  HttpClient.SendAsync(), and block on the result with Task.Result() or
  something similar.  But are there any risks to taking an application
  that is (seemingly) working ok and adding either of the two settings
  mentioned above?  I'm interested in the specific risks associated with
  each setting, and how to assess them based on the characteristics of
  my application.
- the appSetting "aspnet:AllowAsyncDuringSyncStages" with value false will do some checking (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that can give you some confidence that your old application won't break if you move it from the legacy ASP pipeline to the new one.  Has anyone had any experience with this?